# Sitecore User Group Germany (Düsseldorf) – June 14, 2018

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

## Overview

**Date/Time (local)**: 13:00–17:30 on June 14, 2018

**Date/Time (UTC)**: 11:00–15:30 on June 14, 2018

**Location**: METRONOM GmbH, Metro-Strasse 1, 40235 Düsseldorf

**Registration is mandatory**: https://www.xing.com/events/sitecore-usergroup-deutschland-dusseldorf-1927811

**Information and contacts**: https://www.sitecore-usergroup.de/

## Sessions

1. **Azure PaaS Deployment mit dem Sitecore Azure Toolkit** – Tim-Patrick Märk
2. **Getting started with JSS** – Ghodrat Ashournia
3. **Sitecore XC im Vergleich mit Commerce 8.2.1** – Christian Hahn
4. **Accelerating everything – SXA at Enterprise Level** – Sebastian Winter + Team
5. **The Sitecore MVP Program** – Tamas Varga

Comment: Added to community events.